# laravel guzzle not working with amadeus api

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, amadeus

I am using Guzzle for retrieving data from Amadeus. It works fine with Postman and also if I call with Ajax it works fine but when I want to retrieve data from the controller it says bad request.

[image]

Postman

[image]

```
    public function agentsTicket(Request $request)
    {
        $client = new Client();

        try {
            $res = $client->Get('https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers', [

                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => ['Bearer','123456789'],
                ],
                'form_params' => [
                    "originLocationCode" => "SYD",
                    "destinationLocationCode" => "BKK",
                    "departureDate" => "2021-11-01",
                    "returnDate" => "2021-11-18",
                    "adults" => "2",
                    "max" => "1",
                ]
            ]);

            $res = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);
            dd($res);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $response = $res->getResponse();
            $result =  json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
            return response()->json(['data' => $result]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're sending the request to the wrong URL. The Postman screenshot lists `v2/shopping...`, while your function is attempting to send it to the oauth URL

Comment: Retry your code and update your error screenshot with the new URL. The error screenshot is still referencing oauth, which means it's referencing the old code, or the error is not in this function.

Comment: `form_params` would be for a POST request. Since you're using `GET`, try `query` instead.  https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#query-string-parameters

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: #aynber Thanks for your help. with your help, I Fixed It.First, the Authorization should be in a single string like 'Bearer 123456789', Second instead of form_params I wrote query now and it's working thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution the first problem was changing authorization from array to string.
The second problem was 'form_params' as #aynber said I changed it to query and now every thing works fine.

```
    public function agentsTicket(Request $request)
    {
        $client = new Client();

        try {
            $res = $client->Get('https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers', [

                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer 123456789',
                ],
                'query' => [
                    "originLocationCode" => "SYD",
                    "destinationLocationCode" => "BKK",
                    "departureDate" => "2021-11-01",
                    "returnDate" => "2021-11-18",
                    "adults" => "2",
                    "max" => "1",
                ]
            ]);

            $res = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);
            dd($res);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $response = $res->getResponse();
            $result =  json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
            return response()->json(['data' => $result]);
        }
    }
```